# Do helpdesk, ticket-system, and customer-support tags provide any help in better categorization of programming questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, meta-tags

Often questions tagged under [helpdesk](/questions/tagged/helpdesk), [ticket-system](/questions/tagged/ticket-system), and [customer-support](/questions/tagged/customer-support) are shopping questions and need Closure Votes. Fortunately there are not many and the community can chip in.

Also, I do believe that these 3 tags are meta tags for Stack Overflow as they cannot stand on their own on any questions.